# vim plugin for node.js programming and syntax highlighting? (and how)

Tags: node.js, vim, vim-plugin, neovim

in the case of javascript syntax highlighting, I just had to download javascript.vim file and place the file in the corresponding folder, and vim would automatically make syntax highlighting when I open .js files.

But how does node.vim work?? Where should I place the node.vim file for vim to understand that I am working on node applications and apply the node syntax highlighting??

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Node *is* JavaScript. Why would it have different syntax highlighting?

Comment: for example,.. keywords like require, http, etc.. they are not highlighted using the javascript.vim file only, I thought it would need some additional help from node.vim or other equivalent files

Comment: Those are not keywords, they are variables: `require` contains a function, and `http` just an object. There is no difference between `require` and `http` on one hand and, say, `numberOfFlags` or `x` on the other. It makes little sense to colour them differently when you can just make new "keywords" simply by installing more packages. Real keywords are a fixed inventory, that can't be redefined or used as identifiers, like `continue`, `function` or `in`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Node.vim](https://github.com/moll/vim-node) has a [few ways to install](https://github.com/moll/vim-node#installing) it listed in its README. Did you have trouble with them?

I personally use and suggest [Pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) together with Git. In Node.vim's case installing it would be only:

```
git clone https://github.com/moll/vim-node.git ~/.vim/bundle/node
```

Pathogen would then find Node.vim on next startup and initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Some third party plugins may *enhance* the defaults but Javascript is supported natively so you don't need to download anything for Vim to detect and highlight `.js` files.
2. What `node.vim` file are you talking about? [Does it come from that plugin](https://github.com/moll/vim-node)?

Comment: YES. I have been searching for plugins for node.js and that was one of them